# Progress at fetching large file over sftp

Tags: backup, bash, sftp

I would like to `get` large file over sftp. I execute following commands:

```
kopparberg:dev marek$ sftp -P 678 marek@server
marek@server's password: 
Connected to server.
sftp> cd backup
sftp> get database.gz /Volumes/www/backup/
Fetching /backup/database.gz to /Volumes/www/backup/database.gz
                                                  9%   44MB   1.4MB/s   05:06 ETA
```

Because it follows some more commands, I decided to write a bash script and I put sftp commands in batchfile.

Bash file looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

#get backup file
sftp -P 678 -o "BatchMode no" -b batchfile.sftp marek@server

#following commands
#...
```

In bacthfile.sftp are just three steps:

```
cd backup
get database.gz /Volumes/www/backup/
quit
```

The problem is that I do not see progress when I run the bash file. Is there any rational explanation behind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just use a single SCP command instead?

```
scp -P 678 marek@server:/backup/database.gz /Volumes/www/backup/
```

I also believe that using this method will give you the desired output evern when run from a script.

Comment: I was trying with `scp` before. It looks like I had a typo. TY!

Comment: I don't use it because modern-Linux `scp` doesn't support `scp2`. And OpenVMS doesn't support `scp1`, which is what you offer.

Comment: PS: https://community.hpe.com/t5/operating-system-openvms/scp1-compatibility-mode-is-not-supported/td-p/5699315#M46178:~:text=the%20TCP%2FIP%20Services%20scp%20server%20speaks%20only%20scp2

Answer (score 1):

rsync over sftp will do that for you, no scripting required:

```
rsync -av --progress -e 'ssh -p 678' marek@server:backup/database.gz /Volumes/www/backup/
```

Comment: Note that this requires rsync to be installed on both machines.